# Is it possible to check is an image is a cropped part of other image with google-cloud-vision?

Tags: google-cloud-vision

I'm trying to check is the pair of images actually the larger original and the cropped image from it. It is possible to do with google-cloud-vision?

Comment: You are trying to determine if 1 image is a crop of another image? Is the smaller image an actual crop of the larger image or is the smaller image a completely different image that might be of the same object?

Comment: @Brendan it may be cropped and also processed somehow, say resoluion would be changed of turned into black and white

Comment: but all the details are of the same images, say a house shot with the same people walking around it, not the series of shots from the same points depicting the same house and different people.